# How and when to access in Gradle a property?

Tags: gradle

I have the following in `build.gradle`:

```
PlatformUmbrella platformUmbrella = PlatformUmbrella.create(System.properties['module.status'])

task setClBeforePublish << platformUmbrella.beforePublish

project.tasks.publish.doLast platformUmbrella.afterPublish
```

and `gradle.properties` has ``` module.status = snapshot``gradlew properties ``` outputs:

```
module.status: snapshot
```

But when either `System.properties['module.status']` or `gradle.properties['module.status']` is retrieved, `null` is returned (presumably because properties haven't been processed yet). Accessing `gradle.properties['module.status']` inside a `gradle.taskGraph.whenReady` closure also returns `null`. What's the right way to access the 'module.status' setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contents of gradle.properties will be automatically loaded into the project's "extra" properties extension, which are accessed via `project.ext`.

In your case, try `project.ext["module.status"]` instead.

Comment: I may be misremembering but I thought I read somewhere that `project.ext` is deprecated. Anyway, even if that's true, this works. Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, `project.ext` has not been deprecated. I did forget, though, that it's not necessary to reference the `ext` part when *reading* "dynamic" properties, so you could just use `project["module.status"]` in your scenario. But if you want to check if a property exists, you'd have to do something like `project.ext.has("module.status")`, and if you want to set dynamic properties in your script, you'd have to do something like `project.ext["module.status"] = "snapshot"` or `project.ext.newProp = "newValue"`.